# Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:jar

Tags: java, android, gradle

I am newbie in Android Studio Platform. I am getting this error 
" Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:jar "

Currently my version Android Studio is 3.5.0.
I Have added google() on build.gradle repositories

This is my build.gradle (Project)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {

        jcenter()
    google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    google()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

This is my build.gradle (Module app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.kartik.barcode"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:jar:28.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0'
    //implementation 'com.android.support:design:jar:28.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.0.2@aar'
    implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.0'
   // implementation 'com.android.support:design:jar:28.0.0-alpha1'//for The edittext animation
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.0.0'//for firebase
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:19.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
}
```

I am still getting this error:
ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:jar
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use **`PROPER`** version. There is no **<s>jar</s>** in this dependency.

Use stable

```
   implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'  //28.0.0-alpha1
```

**FYI**

> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the
>   google-services plugin or or updating the version of
>   com.google.android.gms to 11.4.2

You should upgrade below version

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'
```

It will be good approach if you use upgraded classpath

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
```

Comment: Thankyou sir for replying. I have change it. But now im getting error : " Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin or or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 11.4.2."

Comment: @AzimAzman yes valid error . Just upgrade version `com.google.android.gms:`

Comment: I am sorry Sir, I have added the '''com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0''' but the error still came out

Comment: In your project level `build.gradle`  change version off your google-services library  `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'`